# Find JSON object path by boolean value from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

How can I find path to object with property `"is_true": true`?

JSON in data column:

```js
[
  {
    "myData": {},
    "is_true": true
  },
  {
    "myData": {},
    "is_true": false
  },
  {
    "myData": {},
    "is_true": false
  }
]
```

Failed attempts:

```sql
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, "all", true) AS booleanObject FROM my_table
```

and...

```sql
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, "all", "true") AS booleanObject
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, "all", "%true%") AS booleanObject
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, "all", true) AS booleanObject
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, "all", 1) AS booleanObject
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, "all", true, NULL, "$") AS booleanObject
```

etc.

Comment: what is your expected output from this.

Comment: Expected output: If search for "true" `$[0].is_true` else paths contain "false" values `$[1].is_true, $[2].is_true` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like `JSON_SEARCH` only searches string values. You could use brute force:

```sql
SELECT x.i, JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[', x.i, ']')) AS obj
FROM t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
) AS x ON x.i < JSON_LENGTH(t.data)
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$[', x.i, '].is_true')) = true
```

If you're using MySQL 8 then a more elegant option is to use `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT x.i, x.obj
FROM t
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t.data, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
  i FOR ORDINALITY,
  is_true BOOLEAN PATH '$.is_true',
  obj JSON PATH '$'
)) AS x
WHERE x.is_true = true
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=557fb94231491e8a1d2d36f50ffb3b64)

Answer (score 1):

This is an unintuitive option and you should be careful with performance issues:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_SEARCH(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, '$[*].is_true'),
          ', ',
          '", "'
        ),
        '[',
        '["'
      ),
      ']',
      '"]'
    ), 'all', 'true') `positions`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=074e1a9b84db8b9f403d4b8837fd1115).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(is_true, "$[0].is_true") AS is_true
FROM table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(is_true, "$[0].is_true") = 1
```

Comment: I tried the same query but I have over 500k lines in the table and I didn't wait to response. Looks like this query too slow. Search for 1 line takes 0.007sec., 500.000 * 0.007 = 3500 sec... Also I would like to find true value in this way: `JSON_EXTRACT(is_true, "$[*].is_true") = true` but this query not allows to find data when used `*` sign.

Comment: Did you try JSON_EXTRACT(is_true, "$.is_true") = true. And also dont return all of the data use limit and offset so you can paginate.

Comment: If I search for  `JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].is_true")` it returns rows "[true, false, false, false....]" else if I search for `JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].is_true") = true` it always returns `0`. But if I search for some string value `JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$[*].string_value"), "all", "myString")` all is correct and I receive result with collection of paths to properties like: `["$[1]", "$[2]", "$[3]", "$[4]", "$[5]", "$[6]"....]` if I search for `is_true` property I always receive NULL result.